# SOLR querying "less than" and "greather than" symbols

Tags: solr, lucene, lucene.net, solrnet

One of the fields in SOLR, lets call it Customers_txt has value like this:

```
qwe<asd>zxc
```

I am trying to query it like this:

```
Customers_txt:(*qwe<asd>zxc*)
```

But the query executes with no results.
If i query it like this

```
Customers_txt:(*qwe*)
```

i get the result

```
"Customers_txt": [ "qwe<asd>zcx"]
```

But there is possibility that i will find lots of unnecessary records what contain `qwe` as part of the string.
If i execute a query without `*` like this `Customers_txt:(qwe<asd>zxc)`
I get the result back. But i need to find this even if this is a substring, lets say `AAAqwe<asd>zxcAAA`, so i need these asterisk marks.
But as well i need to find the strings with these special symbols in them(`<` and `>`).
This also applyes to symbols `[`, `]` and `:`

Answer (score 0):

You should try below mentioned things:

- You need to look into schema.xml file what kindly of tokenizers/filter factories you are using for the **field type**?
- Also try to do the this query on Solr admin panel with debugQuery=true and see what query is being parsed to?

Comment: here's what fieldType is used

    `<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer>
          <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
          <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
      </fieldType>`

Comment: And results of debugQuery
`"debug": {
    "rawquerystring": "Customers_txt:(*iop<oip>opi*)",
    "querystring": "Customers_txt:(*iop<oip>opi*)",
    "parsedquery": "Customers_txt:*iop<oip>opi*",
    "parsedquery_toString": "Customers_txt:*iop<oip>opi*",
    "explain": {},
    "QParser": "LuceneQParser",`

Comment: I didn't get time to look into it in deeper. If you are facing issue with special character like angular brackets; have you tried replacing these with "?". You query will look like :*iop?oip?opi*

Comment: No, it does not help.
Looks like SOLR does not search for '<' and '>' as replacement for '?'